# Blurring Effect Widget

Tags: qt, photoshop, transparent, blurry

Is there a way in Photoshop to create a button/rectangle for a widget which has a transparent blurred effect, so that it shows the background image through the rectangle but it's blurred?

Such as in this example of a jailbreak tweek: [image]

I tried playing with the opacity which makes it transparent but I'm not sure how to achieve this blurred look.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code snipped for fast Blur for QImage, just Blurr background once and set it as background

```
QImage MainWindow::blurred(const QImage& image, const QRect& rect, int radius, bool          alphaOnly)
{
int tab[] = { 14, 10, 8, 6, 5, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2 };
int alpha = (radius < 1) ? 16 : (radius > 17) ? 1 : tab[radius-1];

QImage result = image.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
int r1 = rect.top();
int r2 = rect.bottom();
int c1 = rect.left();
int c2 = rect.right();

int bpl = result.bytesPerLine();
int rgba[4];
unsigned char* p;

int i1 = 0;
int i2 = 3;

if (alphaOnly)
i1 = i2 = (QSysInfo::ByteOrder == QSysInfo::BigEndian ? 0 : 3);

for (int col = c1; col <= c2; col++) {
    p = result.scanLine(r1) + col * 4;
    for (int i = i1; i <= i2; i++)
        rgba[i] = p[i] << 4;

    p += bpl;
    for (int j = r1; j < r2; j++, p += bpl)
        for (int i = i1; i <= i2; i++)
            p[i] = (rgba[i] += ((p[i] << 4) - rgba[i]) * alpha / 16) >> 4;
}

for (int row = r1; row <= r2; row++) {
    p = result.scanLine(row) + c1 * 4;
    for (int i = i1; i <= i2; i++)
        rgba[i] = p[i] << 4;

    p += 4;
    for (int j = c1; j < c2; j++, p += 4)
        for (int i = i1; i <= i2; i++)
            p[i] = (rgba[i] += ((p[i] << 4) - rgba[i]) * alpha / 16) >> 4;
}

for (int col = c1; col <= c2; col++) {
    p = result.scanLine(r2) + col * 4;
    for (int i = i1; i <= i2; i++)
        rgba[i] = p[i] << 4;

    p -= bpl;
for (int j = r1; j < r2; j++, p -= bpl)
    for (int i = i1; i <= i2; i++)
        p[i] = (rgba[i] += ((p[i] << 4) - rgba[i]) * alpha / 16) >> 4;
}

for (int row = r1; row <= r2; row++) {
    p = result.scanLine(row) + c2 * 4;
    for (int i = i1; i <= i2; i++)
        rgba[i] = p[i] << 4;

    p -= 4;
    for (int j = c1; j < c2; j++, p -= 4)
        for (int i = i1; i <= i2; i++)
            p[i] = (rgba[i] += ((p[i] << 4) - rgba[i]) * alpha / 16) >> 4;
}

return result;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, i don't know QML good enough. by the way, this code was pulled for qt's own blur effect, it was undocumanted or something, but in recent versions i think they may implemented it already, maybe try @AmazingSixty's advice, though i really don't know if that is possible in QML

Answer (score 1):

I would duplicate the layer with the photo and delete the parts that you don't want blurred (or hide them with a mask). The blur effect is achieved with a blur filter. That photo looks like a lens blur. Go to Filter > Blur > Lens Blur. On the slider options in the dialog box, move the Radius slider to right (approx 24). Then apply a new layer on top with a black rectangle set to around 15% opacity. As long as the black rectangle and the duplicate blurred photo are the same size and the layers locked together, you'll get that blurred effect. It will look like the button is blurring the background.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can pull something through using `QGraphicsEffect`.

You can basically apply `QGraphicsOpacityEffect` to the top widget and apply `QGraphicsBlurEffect` to the underlying widget.

Read the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qgraphicseffect.html#QGraphicsEffect) to have a clear understanding.